# Can't open txt files in c++ program with Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, ifstream, visual-studio-2019

I just started using Visual Studio 2019 after using XCode for a while. 
I was always able to open txt files in XCode but now
I can't open them in Visual Studio 2019.

Basically what I do is I press "Start Without Debugging" in the "Debug" tab I and get the error message "File Did Not Open!" from the else statement that I wrote. I am not sure if it has something to do with where the txt file is located or with the file path.

Below is the simple program that I've so far been using
to figure out how to open txt files in Visual Studio 2019:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fobj;
    fobj.open("input.txt");

    if (fobj)
    {
        cout << "File Opened!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "File Did Not Open!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your evidence and proof that there's a file called "input.txt" in this ***process's current directory***? Note: the existence of some file somewhere in your computer, even in the same directory where this C++ source lives, proves absolutely nothing.

Comment: In Visual Studio the current working directory when run your program from the ide is the same folder as the project file (unless you changed the default).

Comment: *I have trouble* is not a problem description unless you tell us specifically what *trouble* you're having. You've not explained a problem here.

Comment: Just use `if (fobj.is_open())`

Comment: If you have the file in the proper folder discussed in my last comment make sure it is named correctly. The default windows feature of hiding extensions for known file types could be getting in your way. Perhaps your file is actually named `input.txt.txt` but the hiding extensions has made this not easy to spot.

Comment: @drescherjm Is the project file the file that ends with .sln?

Comment: That is the solution file. If you have only 1 project it should be the same folder.

Comment: The project folder is the folder that has the Debug folder with the .ilk and .pdb files, and the folder with project name that has the source files such as .cpp and other files like .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters right?

Comment: Now about the input.txt file yeah I checked and it is named correctly and right now I have it in the folder that has the .cpp, .vcxproj and .vcxproj.files.

Comment: ***.vcxproj and .vcxproj.files*** That should be the correct folder. Check your project's debug settings. What I mean by that is in the debuging settings for the Debug configuration the working directory should be set to `$(ProjectDir)`

Comment: It's set $(ProjectDir) but when I run the code it still prints out the error message from the else statement.

Answer (score 3):

You are using a **relative** file path to open the file. The calling process' "current working directory" is likely not what you are expecting (check with [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) to verify). Always use **absolute** file paths when opening files.

For instance, if the file is in the same folder as your EXE, use [`GetModuleFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea) to get the EXE's full path, then replace the filename portion with your desired filename:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[MAX_PATH] = {};
    ::GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, filename, MAX_PATH);
    ::PathRemoveFileSpecA(filename);
    ::PathCombineA(filename, filename, "input.txt");

    std::ifstream fobj;
    fobj.open(filename);

    if (fobj)
    {
        std::cout << "File Opened!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "File Did Not Open!\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```